# Adding SQL EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION causes Syntax error and Unexpected text

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax-error, teradata

I would like to add several handlers to the procedure, simplified current version look like this:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DM.AZ_SP ( IN IN_S_DATE DATE, IN IN_E_DATE DATE, OUT sqlMsg_result VARCHAR(133) )
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

    DECLARE V_S_DATE DATE;
    DECLARE V_E_DATE DATE;
    DECLARE V_REPORT_DATE DATE;
    DECLARE sted_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    SET V_S_DATE = IN_S_DATE;
    SET V_E_DATE = IN_E_DATE;
    SET sted_id = 0;



    SET sted_id = 1;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
            BEGIN
                insert into DM.t_sp_logs values (
                    current_timestamp
                ,   'AZ_SP'
                ,   sted_id
                ,   'ERROR code: '  || :SQL_CODE
                );   -- Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3707):Syntax error, expected something like an 'END' keyword between ';' and the 'DECLARE' keyword.'.
            END; 
END; -- Unexpected text 'END'.
```

What is wrong here and how to fix that?

Comment: I suppose you need to add `CREATE OR ` to the beginning of the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an order of declarations:

```
DECLARE variables/condition handlers
DECLARE cursors
DECLARE handlers
```

The first `SET` ends the declaration part.

You need to move the SET *after* the handler.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DM.AZ_SP ( IN IN_S_DATE DATE, IN IN_E_DATE DATE, OUT sqlMsg_result VARCHAR(133) )
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

    DECLARE V_S_DATE DATE;
    DECLARE V_E_DATE DATE;
    DECLARE V_REPORT_DATE DATE;
    DECLARE sted_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
            BEGIN
                insert into DM.t_sp_logs values (
                    current_timestamp
                ,   'AZ_SP'
                ,   sted_id
                ,   'ERROR code: '  || :SQL_CODE
                );   -- Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3707):Syntax error, expected something like an 'END' keyword between ';' and the 'DECLARE' keyword.'.
            END; 

    SET V_S_DATE = IN_S_DATE;
    SET V_E_DATE = IN_E_DATE;
    SET sted_id = 0;



    SET sted_id = 1;

END;
```

or you use nested BEGIN/END, there's a new declaration part after each BEGIN

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DM.AZ_SP ( IN IN_S_DATE DATE, IN IN_E_DATE DATE, OUT sqlMsg_result VARCHAR(133) )
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

    DECLARE V_S_DATE DATE;
    DECLARE V_E_DATE DATE;
    DECLARE V_REPORT_DATE DATE;
    DECLARE sted_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    SET V_S_DATE = IN_S_DATE;
    SET V_E_DATE = IN_E_DATE;
    SET sted_id = 0;



    SET sted_id = 1;
    BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
            BEGIN
                insert into DM.t_sp_logs values (
                    current_timestamp
                ,   'AZ_SP'
                ,   sted_id
                ,   'ERROR code: '  || :SQL_CODE
                );   -- Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3707):Syntax error, expected something like an 'END' keyword between ';' and the 'DECLARE' keyword.'.
            END;
        ..... 
    END;
END;
```